# Unable to access localhost:8080 from eclipse springboot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I am running a simple springboot demoapplication
[image]

But while accessing the localhost:8080 from browser, I see "Site can't be reached error".
What could be the issue here.
Even the port is not occupied(checked via netstat).
Below are the logs, displayed:-

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.4.RELEASE)

2020-10-12 19:45:54.694  INFO 19756 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on 8-UJLOP with PID 19756 (C:\Users\abc\Downloads\demo\demo\target\classes started by rsoni in C:\Users\abc\Downloads\demo\demo)
2020-10-12 19:45:54.695  INFO 19756 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : The following profiles are active: @spring.profiles.active@
2020-10-12 19:45:54.791  INFO 19756 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 0.312 seconds (JVM running for 0.869)
```

Application.properties-- it only has the below mentioned property

[image]

pom XML

[image]

[image]

Comment: Share whats in your dev profile’s properties file.

Comment: Are you sure it listens on 8080?  do you have `spring-boot-starter-web` on your project? I'm not seeing all the prints that usually come with it (including the port it listens on

Comment: seeing your pom and properties file would help

Comment: you should check if projects port is 8080. Also, sometimes, internet explorer doesnot open localhost:8080. Maybe, problem is your browser. If you have more than one browser, try the other browser too.

Comment: Shared the details regarding pom.xml and application.properties file.

Comment: include `spring-boot-starter-web` in your dependencies.

Comment: @NirLevy@Sajjad, thanks.....after adding spring boot starter web dependency, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following dependency to pom.xml worked:-

spring-boot-starter-web